# Git exception in Eclipse when code not using git

Tags: java, eclipse, git, exception

I get this error whenever I open an external folder from inside my running Java program:

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

As far as I can tell, everything is working perfectly and the error perplexes me.

The code used to open the folder:

```
File file = new File(saveDirectory);
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
try {
    desktop.open(file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am building the program in Eclipse Juno and it is a git repository as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [bug](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/2039) regarding this same error.

Update the bundler and see if it works. Apparently some bundlers remove the `.git` directory.

Comment: I've just been through all of the git preferences on eclipse, no mention of a bundler of any kind, also I'm struggling to comprehend what it is even for and what Gems are... I'll have another look tomorrow methinks, thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: It may not be your case, but I thought it may be helpful to know that sometimes these are in fact bugs and not programmer's fault. ; )